# javascript redirecting mobile devices if referrer is not my domain

Tags: javascript, mobile, replace, user-agent, referrer

For reasons too long to explain here, I want to use javascript to redirect visitors from my index page to my mobile subdomain if they are certain devices using userAgent.

The issue I have is the mobile site has a "view full site" link that sends you to the index page. This creates a loop condition.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

---

**If** the referring url is not my own domain **and** the user agent matches, then redirect to the mobile subdomain.

---

I am close but missing something.

```
    if   (document.referrer != "mydomain.com" &&
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/Googlebot-Mobile/i))); {
        location.replace("https://m.mydomain.com");
        }
```

Comment: You can NEVER rely on referrer

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is a bit funny and you have a semicolon where you shouldnt.

The the referrer condition will be ignored since its just or'ed with the other conditions. Put all the OR's in brackets and it should work.

```
if   (document.referrer != "mydomain.com" &&
            ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.match(/Googlebot-Mobile/i)))) {
        location.replace("https://m.mydomain.com");
        }
```

Having a link is a good idea since it shows youre aware you can never second guess the user (and device recognition) 100%.

As mplungjan says its not very robust to rely on the referrer. I would recommend you store some 'session' information registering the users intention to view on the full site. This can then override your switch.

Most mobile browsers support sessionStorage which you could use to keep track of this (eg `sessionStorage['site'] = 'full'`) although I've had issues with iOS and private mode (doesnt store anything in private mode).

Comment: **interesting...**
The reason I was going the referrer route is I do not have to rely on the mobile device accepting cookies and not being in private (like I keep mine iPhone)

I am open to suggestions, arguments and ideas.

I thought that since I am saying anything buy my referrer it would be easily understood. If it does not get a referrer no big deal... It still has to pass the userArgent.
What do you mean as "robust"?